# Python : conditionally modify user input

Tags: python-3.4

I have a .txt that I search for data which is formated as such: 'nnnnn' where n=integer.

For that I search with :

```
with open("path of file to search") as search:
    num = input ("data : ")
```

This works fine if the user input has the same format 'nnnnn'. My issue is that the input can vary from: 'nnnnn' to 'n' and 'MM0nnnnn'(the data in the file has always a lenght of 5 going from '0000n' to 'nnnnn').

I want therefore to add two conditions to the input :

1. if MM0 in input not to take it into account
2. while input lenght is < 5 to add zeros to the left

I tried but no succes with:

for 1  :

```
if 'MM0' in num :
        num.replace('MM0','')
```

for 2 :

```
while len(num) < 5:
    num.append('0','0')
```

I've seen this on the web but I'm certainly using it wrong.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, so I don't know if it is possible with python or not but I can tell you why your code doesn't work. `num` is a variable returned by `input()`. The `input()` method only returns value after you pressed enter on your keyboard. You code only changes the value of `num`.

Comment: @Jeremy : Thank for your help, I finally found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out :

```
for line in search:

        if 'MM0' in str(num) and str(num).replace('MM0','') in line: #Remove MM0 if present in input
            print (line)


        if str(num).zfill(5) in line:  #Fill with zeros to the left if input <5
            print(line)
```

It may help someone out there.